# How to auto update a socket.io with arduino?

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, arduino, serial-communication

I'm currently working on an arduino project. Were the arduino is communicating with a NodeJS server via serialport and the server send data to client via socket.io

I have already got the information to appear in the browser (h1 tag with a 'real-time' counter of arduino).

The problem is that for the counter to be updated I have to refresh the browser. My goal is to ensure that this information is updated automatically. I looked through the documentation and didn't find any events for socket.io that refers to the update.

Here my code:

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
let expressPort = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Socket:
const io = require('socket.io')(http);


// Arduino Stuff:
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const ReadLine = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
const port = new SerialPort('COM3', { baudRate: 9600 });
const parser = port.pipe(new ReadLine({ delimiter: '\r\n' }));

parser.on('data', data => {
    let counter = data;
    console.log(counter);

    io.on('connection', socket => {
        io.emit('arduino', counter);
    });

});

parser.on('error', error => {
    console.log(error);
});

// Express stuff
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/');
});


http.listen(expressPort, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port: ${expressPort}`);
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Arduino Stuff</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="counter"></h1>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</body>
```

app.js

```
const socket = io();

socket.on('arduino', data => {
    console.log(data);
    const counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    counter.innerHTML = data;
});
```

Thank you very much in advance :)

EDIT:

I forgot to put the arduino code, but basically it's just a counter with dealay:

```
int counter = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(++counter, DEC);
  delay(3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm stupid, just don't wrap de emit method with  **io.on('connection'...),** there is not a 'update' method per se, the emit method is enough to achieve this, but, if you insert that inside the 'connection', well, this it's just called in the first connection, ergo, just displayed the info in the refresh.

Result:

```
parser.on('data', data => {
    let counter = data;
    console.log(counter);

    io.emit('arduino', counter);

});
```

Sorry for waste your time guys :(